# Why GitHub action fails to push the docker image?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, ghcr, github-container-registry

I have a lot of GitHub actions that push built docker images to the [GitHub Container Repository](https://ghcr.io).

Basically, what I do is to have two steps in my job:

```
      - name: Log in to GitHub Container Repository
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
          
      - name: Push the image
        run: |
          docker push ghcr.io/organization_name_here/repository_name_here:latest
```

This works out of the box fo all of my organizations and repositories.

However, for one very particular repository, I get this error:

```
Run docker push ghcr.io/organization_name_here/repository_name_here:latest
The push refers to repository [ghcr.io/holismreact/webrtc]
e6ff916ab651: Preparing
9d5288bc1c41: Preparing
bf5ee69d004a: Preparing
20e664c3d99e: Preparing
b3031b5001d5: Preparing
a303372b2caa: Preparing
39982b2a789a: Preparing
a303372b2caa: Waiting
39982b2a789a: Waiting
denied: permission_denied: write_package
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for me either.

The workaround is to use a GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT) from one of the users in the organization.

```
echo "${{ secrets.DAVE_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u DaveTheDeveloper --password-stdin
```

There is a whispering of a permission `OrganizationPackages: write` but it does not exist for me.